# How to remove background from image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I need to remove the everything in this image except the tree and its leaves. 
I am looking for suggestions on how to remove everything that isn't a part of the tree. The image I need to process is [image: here.]

Comment: As others have said, have you looked into OpenCV?OpenCV has a Python API which you can use for image processing. Here is a link which describe how to use OpenCv for image segmentation. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html

Comment: This is a difficult problem. I don't envy you. But it's also not a suitable question for SO, this is not a code writing service. Please read the documentation at the following links: [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [ask].

Comment: I really didn't know where to start, so I was looking for suggestions. I will ask better q's in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This question IS broad. But for the image given by you there is a workaround. You can segment the foreground by converting your image to another color space.

Notice how contrasting the blue sky and the clouds are with respect to the leaves in the foreground. Applying a simple threshold on the hue channel will segment most of the leaves.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Jackson/Desktop/leaves.jpg', 1)
im = cv2.resize(im, (0, 0), fx = 0.5, fy = 0.5)   

imhsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow('Hue', imhsv[:,:,0])
```

[image]

```
#--- Otsu threshold ---
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imhsv[:,:,0], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
```

[image]

```
#--- Masking with the original image ---
fin = cv2.bitwise_and(im, im, mask = thresh)
cv2.imshow('fin', fin)
```

[image]

**Note:**

This is not a general solution. This is specific for this image and images that have contrasting colors. For a more generalized approach you could try GrabCut algorithm which is destined to work for simple images.